# Derivation (Matsumura: Commutative algebra)

Tags: commutative-algebra

I am reading Masumura, Commutative algebra, Chapter 10: Derivation.
The following is in pages 177, 178.

Two extensions $(C, \varepsilon, i)$ and $(C_1, \varepsilon_1, i_1)$ are said to be *isomorphic* if there exists a ring homomorphism $f: C \to C_1$ such that $\varepsilon_1 f= \varepsilon$ and $fi  =i_1$ [it means the diagram commutes]. Such $f$ is necessarily unique.

Question: Why is $f$ unique?

Thanks!

Comment: it is easy to see that $f$ is isomorphism (use the snake lemma)